# Node.js downloading image with authorization

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to adapt code which can download an image to be able to download an image from a website that requires an authorization in the headers. Here is the code I am try to adapt:

```
var options = {
    host: 'subdomain',
    //uri: 'full url,
    //uri: 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/51/Google.png',
    port: 80,
    path: "/secure/attachment/" + req.params.attachmentFileName,
    //method: 'GET',
    headers: {
        Authorization: "Basic " + new Buffer(jiraUsername + ":" + jiraPassword, "utf8").toString("base64")
    }
};

var download = function(uri, filename, callback){
    request.head(uri, function(err, res, body){
        console.log("Res", res);
        console.log('content-type:', res.headers['content-type']);
        console.log('content-length:', res.headers['content-length']);

        request(uri).pipe(fs.createWriteStream(filename)).on('close', callback);
    });
    //http.request(options).pipe(fs.createWriteStream(filename)).on('close', callback);
};

download(options, appDir+file, function(){
    console.log('done');
    res.sendFile(appDir+file);
});
```

When I include `uri` in the options, the code goes into an infinite loop checking for `res.headers`. If I don't include it, I get an error that `Cannot read property 'headers' of undefined`. I couldn't find any documentation of `request.head` so I'm not sure if I'm using it correctly.

Ideally this is similar to the `download()` I'd like to use instead:

```
var download = function(options, filename, callback){
    request(options).pipe(fs.createWriteStream(filename)).on('close', callback);
```

But when I use that, I get that `options.uri is a required argument`. I can work around this by defining uri inside options.

Comment: Why are you sending a `HEAD` request at all?

Comment: When you call `download`, you're passing `options` as first parameter. But inside `download`, the first parameter is handled like it's a URI.